# can we back with findNavController().navigateUp() with FragmentNavigator.Extras?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation, clean-architecture

this is what AI (chat GPT-3) said to me

```
    val extras = intent.extras
if (extras != null) {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    navController.navigateUp()
    navController.navigate(R.id.destination_id_to_navigate, extras)
}
```

i didn't want it due to do twice navigate.

---

can i make like

```
val extras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(foo to bar)
findNavController().navigateUp(extras) //error
```

?